# What is this variable length date encoding format?

Tags: database, date, encoding, format

I've came across what seems an efficient mechanism of handling date range searches.

1. What is the formal name for this technique?
   *Given where this post ended up on Google, it's definitely not `variable-length date encoding`
2. What database/query languages uses this date indexing/encoding mechanism?
3. Is there a canonical way of calculating entries marked with a star?

My incomplete understanding is:

> Date-ranges are queried using character strings, limited to 7-bit

> Every date-range can be queried by multiple strings, which are 'hierarchical' (longer strings are more precise)

> In this particular scheme, there are at least *8* date formats (but all are searched with the same query `date=?%20%00%00%00%00` or `date=?%02%00%00` would both be valid)

For the implementation I've seen:

- Dates center at 01-01-1970, negative and positive dates are possible (this question just describes positive dates)
- Individual characters are kept to %00 - %7F to avoid encoding issues
- Since queries start with a single-char wildcard by convention, this table starts with the second character.

| 2nd-char | Following chars | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| %02 | 2 | ? | > 500 year |  |  |  |  |  |
| %01 | 3 | ? | ? | >500 year |  |  |  |  |
| %40 | 3 | ? | ? | >500 year |  |  |  |  |
| %20 | 4 | ? | 553years? | 1950-1951 days | 12-13 days |  |  |  |
| %10 | 5 | ? | ? | 3181-3182 days | 25-26 days | * |  |  |
| %08 | 6 | ? | ? | ~6362days | ~50days | * | * |  |
| %04 | 7 | ? | ? | ~12725days | ~100days | * | * | * |

Comment: What is the URL of the info you have found? Do you have any code? If so, what is the name of the library/function?

Comment: No code, no URL -- that's what I'm looking for!  The table was transcribed from paper notes, so errors/inaccuracies may be present.